# rabbitmq connection recovery issue in spring cloud stream

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I am new to `spring` , I am using a `rabbitmq` which is in the `spring-cloud-stream` . Here I am using version of `rabbitmq` `4.0.7` . Version of `spring-AMQP` `1.7`. I checked all the things, but I am not able to resolve the issue. So, the error is

```
Caught an exception during connection recovery!
java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:350)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.recoverConnection(AutorecoveringConnection.java:476)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.beginAutomaticRecovery(AutorecoveringConnection.java:444)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.access$000(AutorecoveringConnection.java:53)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection$1.shutdownCompleted(AutorecoveringConnection.java:383)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ShutdownNotifierComponent.notifyListeners(ShutdownNotifierComponent.java:75)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:578)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:37)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:367)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:293)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:538)
    ... 1 more


Channel channel = (Channel)message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL);
```

This way I am creating the channel, I have a `application.yml` file where I set all the binding properties. Can any tell me the reason about this ?

Answer (score 0):

1.7.1 disables auto recovery by default (unless you inject a preconfigured Rabbit `ConnectionFactory` into the `CachingConnectionFactory`).

It was incorrectly enabled by default in 1.7.0.

Spring AMQP doesn't need autorecovery, it has had its own connection recovery mechanisms since 1.0.

The current 1.7.x version is 1.7.6; the current (preferred) version is 2.0.2.

This doesn't explain the EOFException (auto recovery still, normally, works - it's just not needed).